# Where to ask about reverse engineering of electronics of a game

Tags: support, site-recommendation

Where to ask about the concept of a game electronics design or idea?

For example, I'm planning with some friends of me to make a shooting game like Father.io [[see this link for video of the game]](https://www.father.io/), and we're very confused about the teknik/tools/sensors/methods they are using for detecting other players and shooting them when aiming on them.

Image processing, thermal detection, calculating players position and orientation, we thought almost in everything but nothing seemed to be working.

We're now thinking of asking others on the internet to help us making a reverse engineering for the game and figure out how did they make it.

I found at first two sites that I can post my question on ([gamedev](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com) and [reverse engineering](http://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com)), but seems that the first SE website is not for such questions and the second SE one is only for programming languages.

Where is the pest place to ask such questions?

Comment: Why do you get the impression that Reverse Engineering is only for programming language? [Their help/on-topic page](http://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) says otherwise. You can't judge a site by what you see on their homepage - sometimes, one topic or subset may dominate the community, but that doesn't mean that other things are off-topic there. I'm not sure if your questions will be on-topic there or not, but hardware and tools are on-topic there.